# Why are return values not present in autos window in VS2013 whilst debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

When stepping out of a method in Visual Studio 2013 when debugging, it would normally show the return value of that method in the autos window. On my machine, this is not working. There is no entry in the autos window.

In the following example code, when stepping out of `GetX()` I should see an entry in the autos window of the form `ConsoleApplication1.Program.GetX returned true`.

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = GetX();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    private static bool GetX()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue turned out to be with an option that I had turned on in Tools->Debugging called "use managed compatibility mode". Turning this off again solved the issue.

I had done this a while ago due to suffering issues as described in the question that this answer solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21826398/413075 . Since this time I have installed Update 1 and I do not seem to be encountering the original issues now the option is turned off again.